# improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x}dx=$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can somebody please help me with this improper integral?
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x}dx=$$
$$=\int_{1}^{\omega}\frac{x^3}{e^x}dx+\int_{\omega}^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x}dx=$$
I don't know which $\omega$ should i choose and if this way to solve this problem is correct?
Any suggestion would be great

Thanks

Comment: @Buraian It turns out that this integral virtually converges

Comment: Totally independent of Buraian's comment is how to 
interpret the problem.  Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x^3}{e^x}.$
Then $f(x)$ is well defined for any *finite* $x \geq 1.$
Therefore the problem should be interpreted as : calculate
$\displaystyle \lim_{b\to \infty} \int_1^b f(x) dx.$

Comment: This integral does indeed converge, my bad. I have deleted my mistaken comment.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts!

We have $$\int \frac{x^3}{e^x}dx=-e^{-x}x^3+3\int e^{-x}x^2dx$$
$$=-e^{-x}x^3-3e^{-x}x^2+6\int e^{-x}xdx$$
$$=-e^{-x}x^3-3e^{-x}x^2-6e^{-x}x+6\int e^{-x}dx$$
$$=-e^{-x}(x^3+3x^2+6x+6)+C.$$

Now substitute the limits and we have $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{e^x}dx=\frac{16}{e}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to decompose as you can integrate explicitly (the integral in only improper on one side).
For any polynomial,

$$(P(x)e^{-x})'=(P'(x)-P(x))e^{-x},$$

so you need to solve

$$P'(x)-P(x)=x^3.$$

By indeterminate coefficients,

$$3ax^2+2bx+c-ax^3-bx^2-bx-c=x^3$$

is solved by

$$P(x)=-x^3-3x^3-6x-6.$$

Obviously,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)e^{-x}=0.$$

> $$I=-P(1)e^{-1}=16e^{-1}.$$

Comment: what is the idea behind what you did..? I don't quite get it

Comment: @Buraian: the idea is to integrate explicitly in the form $P(x)e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding to integrate 3 times by parts, as per definition of [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}x^3e^{-x}dx=\Gamma(4;1)$$

Comment: $+1$. That’s all !!!.